# Access double click event to open query in listbox

Tags: ms-access, ondoubleclick

I have a listbox in a form that displays all available queries in the database.  I need to setup a double click event that when a query in the list box is selected it opens that query.  In my googling all I'm finding is how to setup a double click event to open a specific record in a form.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this on the Listbox control's *DblClick* event.

```
Private Sub YourListBoxControlName_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    DoCmd.OpenQuery Me.YourListBoxControlName.Value
End Sub
```